# cant pass data from AppComponent to function

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I send the email data to `this.user` in *constructror*.

So it storage in AppComponent, Next i need this variale in function getUserData for import some data...
but the console.log show undefined, and there is also error for `users` :

*Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined*

So what i made wrong? Why i cant pass data using this.?

Update

Now the user.String is string that contain a "xxxx@.xx.com"
But still i cant pass it there. this.user in getUserData is undefind :/

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RewardsComponent } from './rewards/rewards.component';
import { AngularFire,AuthProviders, AuthMethods, FirebaseAuthState } from 'angularfire2';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
declare var firebase: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app works!';
  userData: any = [];
  user: String;

  constructor(public af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {
    af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
      if(auth) {
        this.user = auth.auth.email.toString();
      }
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUserData();
  }

  getUserData() {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("/user");
    ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo(this.user).on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
      this.userData.push(snapshot.val());
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably

```
this.user = auth.auth.email;
```

is storing a string, something like 'someemail@gmail.com'

When you try to access

```
this.user.auth
```

there is no .auth attribute/key, because this.user is not an object.

Also, you have to keep in my mind that af.auth.subscribe is assynchronous code, therefore you can't access this.user in the ngOnInit method, because you don't know if the af.auth.subscribe has been called yet.

Comment: What kind of help do u need?

Comment: i just pass the data to localstorage and clear it after that ^^
I know it isnt good idea. but it work

Answer (score 0):

You should access email since you are assigning only **`email`** ,

```
 console.log(this.user.email);
 var users = this.user.email;
```

if you need to access the whole auth object, then assign it as,

```
 this.user = auth;
```

Comment: This will not be work . 
I have change code a litle. Check it please :)